# Show an other form from main form Qt C++

Tags: c++, forms, qt, graphics, qt-creator

i created a form `mainwindow` class in QT creator, and an action element in a menuBar, and i want that when we click on it, it show an other form called `DataWindow`

Here is my mainwindow.h

```
private slots:
    void on_actionNouvellesDonnees_clicked();
```

Here is my mainwindow.ccp

```
void MainWindow::on_actionNouvellesDonnees_clicked() {
    DataWindow w;
    w.show();
}
```

But when i debug and i click on my action menu, the DataWindow is not showed... and the debug tool said me :

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_actionNouvellesDonnees_clicked()
```

Thanks for any help !

Complete mainwindow.ccp :

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMessageBox>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "datawindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    //QObject::connect(ui->actionNouvellesDonnees, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(on_actionNouvellesDonnees_clicked()));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::on_actionNouvellesDonnees_triggered() {

    DataWindow w;
    w.show();
}
```

Complete mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_actionNouvellesDonnees_triggered();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which signal do you connect on_actionNouvellesDonnees_clicked? If it is an action(like in main menu) correct signal isn't "clicked()", you can use "triggered()".

Try this

```
QObject::connect(ui->actionNouvellesDonnees, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(on_actionNouvellesDonnees_clicked()));
```

Comment: Oh ok thanks it works too ! But the form is showed and closed just after, why ?

Comment: You created window in the stack, at the end of the function it's destroyed. You sould create the window in the heap or better, define it as a class member.

Comment: I don't understand... can you make me an concret exemple ?

Comment: Define DataWindows as a class member, like this
public:
    DataWindow w;

void MainWindow::on_actionNouvellesDonnees_clicked() {
    this->w.show();
}

Comment: I m sorry im a real beginner, it dosn't work too... i have edited my post, now you can see all my code, if you can tell me exacly what i must right... Thanks you very much

Comment: Just move "DataWindow w;" line to class definition in mainwindow.h.

Comment: Thans you so much for your help !

Comment: can you answer at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13350338/use-ui-array-in-a-fonction-qt-c

Answer (score 6):

You said you use

```
    void MainWindow::on_actionNouvellesDonnees_clicked() {
        DataWindow w;
        w.show();
    }
```

This constructs a DataWindow object on the stack, shows it, and leaves the function, immediately destroying the object.

```
    void MainWindow::on_actionNouvellesDonnees_clicked() {
        DataWindow *w = new DataWindow;
        w->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
        w->show();
    }
```

should keep it alive until you manually close the window

Comment: Neat little feature. I hadn't noticed that one before.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `actionNouvellesDonnees` is a `QAction`, which doesn't have a signal called clicked().  Try changing your slot to be:

```
on_actionNouvellesDonnees_triggered()
```

Comment: Oh ok thanks it works ! But the form is showed and closed just after, why ?

Answer (score 1):

Right now all you do is show the window and then delete it as you leave the slot's scope. You have many options to get around this, depending on what you're trying to do and what kind of window `DataWindow` is supposed to be.

**Option 1** - Simple Modal Dialog

If you're just popping up a window that requires the user's immediate attention and nothing else can proceed until they're finished, launch a modal dialog that waits for user entry. [QDialog::exec()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdialog.html#exec) should be substituted for [QDialog::show()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qwidget.html#show).

```
void MainWindow::on_actionNouvellesDonnees_triggered() {
    DataWindow w;
    int result = w.exec();
    switch(result){
        case QDialog::Ok: //etc
            break;
        case QDialog::Cancel: //etc
            break;
        default: //etc
    }
}
```

**Option 2** - Complex Modal Dialog

If this window needs to be queried somehow by other functions, you'd want to make it a member of MainWindow and then create it on the heap during your action.

```
//MainWindow.h
MainWindow {
public:
    MainWindow();
    ...
protected:
    DataWindow* m_datawin;
    ...
}

//mainwindow.cpp
void MainWindow::MainWindow {
    ...
    m_datawin = 0;
}
void MainWindow::on_actionNouvellesDonnees_triggered() {
    if(m_datawin != 0)
        m_datawin->deleteLater(); //you must delete it somewhere. either delete it in the dtor or at the end of this slot, depending on if you need it outside this scope
    m_datawin = new DataWindow();
    m_datawin->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
    int result = m_datawin->exec();
    switch(result){
        case QDialog::Ok: //etc
            break;
        case QDialog::Cancel: //etc
            break;
        default: //etc
    }
}
```

There's also a third option for a nonmodal dialog (or window), but I'll let you read the [QDialog documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdialog.html#details) if that's what you're looking for. Hopefully I got the main idea across.

A fourth option would be to `new DataWindow` in the MainWindow constructor and then `show`/`hide` it in the triggered slot.