# Use UI array in a function Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, graphics, qt-creator, signals-slots

In my Windows forms code, ui is used to define graphical element by default. But I want to modify them in a function, like this:

The problems is that the debug tool tells me that ui is not declared in this scope.

```
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFile>
#include <QTextStream>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "datawindow.h"

void getData(ui){
    QFile inputFile("C:\\pepoles.txt");
        if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
           QTextStream in(&inputFile);



           while ( !in.atEnd() ){
              QString line = in.readLine();
              ui->listWidgetData->addItem(line);
           }
        }
        else{
            QMessageBox::critical(this, "Erreur", "Une erreur s'est produite :(");
        }
    inputFile.close();
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    getData(ui);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionNouvellesDonnees_triggered() {
    w.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `getData()` a member of MainWindow:

```
void MainWindow::getData()
{
    QFile inputFile("C:\\pepoles.txt");
    if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QTextStream in(&inputFile);
        while ( !in.atEnd() ) {
            QString line = in.readLine();
            ui->listWidgetData->addItem(line);
        }
    } else {
        QMessageBox::critical(this, "Erreur", "Une erreur s'est produite :(");
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```

Then, in your constructor:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
getData();
```

I recommend this approach since `ui` contains private members, so it's best to have a member function modify it.

Don't forget to declare `getData()` in the header file of your MainWindow class. You should probably make it private.

And btw, `ui` is not an array. It's an object pointer.

Answer (score 1):

> `void getData(ui){`

That line starts definition of `getData` function, which takes one variable, with *type* `ui` and no name (so it can't be accessed in the function code).

Add type...

```
void getData(MainWindow::Ui *ui){
```